# Google codelab execution for Node Angular app deployment fails

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to execute google cloud code lab by following the steps [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html#3).

I get an error when I run the command - `npm start` on the 4th codelab exercise.

Error details below:

> /home/rohitj559/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/@google-cloud/debug-agent/src/agent/state.js:24
>   var ScopeType = require('vm').runInDebugContext('ScopeType');
>                                 ^ TypeError: require(...).runInDebugContext is not a function
>       at Object. (/home/rohitj559/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/@google-cloud/debug-agent/src/agent/state.js:24:31)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (/home/rohitj559/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/@google-cloud/debug-agent/src/agent/v8debugapi.js:24:27)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
>   cloud-cardboard-viewer@0.1.0 start: `node server.js` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the cloud-cardboard-viewer@0.1.0
>   start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of
>   this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/rohitj559/.npm/_logs/2019-03-16T16_38_05_363Z-debug.log

What is this error exactly and how can I overcome this error?

I looked on the GitHub source file for issue log, couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in this codelabs, and after a 'npm audit fix --force' the node serve is starting. Hope it's work for you.